# Laravel Hash::check returning false even though When i replace them with the string values of the variables it works

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel Hash::check returning false even though When i replace them with the string values of the variables it works. Can someone please help me solve this issue. I cant figure out whats causing the issue. I checked what my variables are returning and they are returning the correct values and i tryed replacing the strings in the hash check to the string value of the variable and it works but when i use the variables it does not work.

```
    public function verifyResetPageAccess(Request $request){
        $email = $request->email; 
        $token = $request->token;

        $exists = DB::table('password_resets')->where('email',$email);
        

        if($exists === null){
            return response(['message'=>'unauthorized'],401);
            
        }else{
          $dbToken = DB::table('password_resets')->where('email',$email)->pluck('token');
        
        
          if (Hash::check($token, $dbToken)) {
            return response(['message'=>'authorized']);
        }else{
              return response(['message'=>'unauthorized'],401);
          }


        }

    }
```

Comment: When you replace which variables with which values?

Comment: In the hash check when I change the $token to the plain text token and when i change the $dbToken to the hashed token it works but when i use the variables it dosent even though i checked the return values of the variables and its showing the correct values.

Comment: Please show us a `$token` and a `$dbToken` from a failed `check()`

Comment: $token would be 1324214124 and the hashed token would be $2y$10$sR9gShvPMJokZNDXC6clOuyGKpQ7LqqWjimsT7uvT9whA9Xry2QPG

Comment: you don't want `pluck` you want `value`, you don't want a list you want 1 single value

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. dbToken was returning an array. I just dident choose an index. its working now